# How to generate shadow png file from Autodesk Maya?

Tags: scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, maya

I am rendering 3d furniture models in Autodesk Maya for an AR app. For showing a shadow of 3d model in scene file I need export of transparent PNG file from Autodesk Maya which I can use as diffuse image for shadow plain. I have attached example of the kind of file needed but I don't know how to generate the same in Autodesk Maya. Please help.[Shadow file generated for chair model.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoZ8D.png)

Comment: For such "how to" questions, the more appropriate place would be the Autodesk Area forums. But nevertheless, most renderers have something called shadow catcher which can be used for such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to generate in Maya a UV texture containing shadows for ARKit / SceneKit models follow these steps (I should say that it's not easy if you're a beginner in Maya):

- Create objects with appropriate shaders
- Create UV map for your models in `UV Editor`
- Activate Maya Software Renderer
- Create lights with Raytraced Shadows
- Don't forget turn `Raytracing` on in Render Options
- Duplicate all 3D objects and lights
- Select an object with cast shadows and a corresponding light

[image]

Go to **`Rendering`** module and choose **Lighting/Shading - Transfer Maps...** menu.

Setup all the properties for ***Shaded Output Map*** and its appropriate location and then press **`Bake`**.

[image]

Also you can output four additional passes in Maya Software Renderer:

- Normal Map
- Displace Map
- Diffuse Map
- Alpha Map

> **If you want just shadows**, without diffuse texture, use white coloured Lambertt Shader in Maya.